# Search na listView com itemView customizado

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma `listView` que possui dois campos de texto (`nome` e `local`) que são retirados de um objeto `Empresa`.

Os exemplos espalhados na internet só mostram `search` em `listViews` normais com somente uma *string*. Como faço para o `search` procurar no campo de texto `nome` dentro do `itemView`?

[image: itemView que é carregada na listView]

Código para procurar em `listView` de *Strings*:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
    {
        // this is your adapter that will be filtered
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
        {
            list.clearTextFilter();
        }
        else
        {
            list.setFilterText(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Empresa> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(Main.this, R.layout.item_view, empresaList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;

            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

            //acha empresa
            Empresa currentEmpresa = empresaList.get(position);

            //preenche lista

            TextView makeTxtEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtNome);
            makeTxtEmpresa.setText(currentEmpresa.getNome());

            TextView makeTxtLocal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtLocal);
            makeTxtLocal.setText(currentEmpresa.getLocal());

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual è a classe da variável `list`?

Comment: para preencher a lista tem uma private class que foi postada agora

Comment: os nomes estao na private class

Comment: Por que não usa o `Filter` no `Adapter`? Nesse tutorial tem um passo-a-passo para implementar um: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html.